# Simulate - meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

Not able to figure out why onChange is not getting called. I added an id but it can't find the element.

File.test.js

```
it("should call onChange event  on renderToDropdown ", () => {
    baseProps.onChange.mockClear();
    wrapper.setState({
    toStatusList:[{
        StatusID:"",
        Name:"",
    }],
   selectedTo:'password test 1'
    });
   wrapper.update() 
   wrapper.find('select[id="testonchange"]').simulate('change',{target: {value: 'password test 1'}} )
 });
```

Also tried the following:

```
wrapper.find('#testonchange').simulate('change',{target: {value: 'password test 1'}} )
```

File.js

```
renderToDropdown = () => {
let list = this.state.toStatusList;
let result = list.map((item) => {
  return <option value={item.StatusID}>{item.Name}</option>
})
result.push(<option value='default' disabled>Select...</option>)
return (
  <select value={this.state.selectedTo} id='testonchange' onChange={(e) => {this.handleToChange(e);}}>
    {result}
  </select>
)
}

handleToChange = (e) => {
this.setState({selectedTo: e.target.value});
```

Using Jest and Enzyme for React JS

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
wrapper.find('select').prop('onChange')({value: 'password test 1'});
```

Comment: I have try this method before and the test passes but it doesn't affect its coverage. Any reason ?

Comment: also : wrapper.find('select').simulate('change', {target:{value: 'password test'}});
     works as well

Comment: It does affect the code coverage as it triggers down the onChange method and passes through all statements and branch which is written inside the function.

Comment: But its not.. the numbers are not changing. I ran with it and without this code. Numbers are the same

Comment: any reason why its not affecting coverage numbers ??

Comment: It is inside of a Modal - my click events are passing but not affecting its coverage

Comment: can you share reproducible code on codesandbox.io? here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/qk60qy3llq

Answer (score 0):

What is wrapper here? Empty instance? Shallow render or mount ?

Comment: shallow wrapper